# Using do while loop and while loop to write a program that will run random guessing game...i stuck at the do while loop

Tags: c++

I have been run a random guessing game. The game secret numbers is from min to max that input by user, the guesser is ask guess the secret number and at the end is supposed to be asked if they would like to play again. There also has to be multiple options for print outs if the guesser is to high or low. Anyways, I want it to check and make sure that the user is inputting numbers, not something silly. So I have been going in circles trying to figure this part out. I am sure it is a easy fix, but I am new to programming and this has got me stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

```
my code should similar to below output images :
[1]http://i62.tinypic.com/wjvuqb.png
[2]http://i57.tinypic.com/2nq9jwm.png
[3]http://i62.tinypic.com/210zss7.png

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int min, max, secret=0, deposit, bet, guess;
    bool again= true;

    string name;
    char reply;

    cout<< setw(80)<< setfill('=')<<"\n\n";
    cout<< setw(45)<< "NUMBER GUESSING GAME!"<<"\n\n";
    cout<< setfill('=')<< setw(80)<<"\n\n";
    cout<< "What ur name?\n";
        getline(cin,name);
        Again:
        cout<< "Pls enter the min & max number\n";
        while(!(cin>>min)||min<0)
        {
            cout<<"Min? ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();   
        }

        while(!(cin>>max)||max<0)
        {
            cout<<"Max? ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }

        while(!(max> min))  
        {
            cout<<"Min is larger than Max\n";
            goto Again;
        }
    cout<< "\nMin: "<<min<<"\nMax: "<<max<<"\n";


    secret= rand() % max+min; 
    cout<<"Enter ur deposit: ";
    cin>> deposit;

AA:      cout<< setw(45)<< "\n\n\n\nRULES OF THE GAME"<<"\n\n";
         cout<< setfill('-')<< setw(80)<<"\n\n";
         cout<< "Guess number between "<< min<< " to "<< max;
         cout<< "\nIf ur guess match, 10 times ur deposit!!";
         cout<< "\nIf ur guess mismatch, lose ur betting amount!!";
         cout<< "\n\n"<< setfill('-')<< setw(80)<<"\n\n\n";
         cout<< "Current Balance: "<<deposit;
         cout<< "\nWhat is ur betting amount? ";
            cin>> bet;

    do{
            cout<< "\n\nEnter a guess to bet: ";
                cin >> guess;

            if (guess > max)
            {
                cout << "Too high!\n\n";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();       
            }
            else if (guess < min)
            {
                cout << "Too low!\n\n";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();
            }


          }while (guess != secret);

                if(guess != secret){
                deposit-=bet;
                cout << "\nThat's it! You got it!\n";
                cout<<"Sorry, U lose RM "<< bet;
            }
            else{
                bet*=10;
                deposit+=bet;
                cout << "\nThat's it! You got it!\n";
                cout<<"Congratulation! U earn RM "<< bet;
            }

        cout<<"\n\nThe secret number was : "<< secret;
        cout<< "\n\n\tCurrent Balance: "<<deposit<< "\n\n\n";

        do{
            cout<< "Wanna play again (y/n)? ";
            cin>> reply;

            if( reply=='y'){
                again= true;
                goto AA;    
            }
            else
                cout<<"\nReally? Ok, try again! ";  
                cin>>reply;
        }while(again==false && reply=='n');

        if(reply=='n'){     
        cout<<"\n\n\n"<< setw(80)<< setfill('+')<<"\n\n";
        cout<< setw(30)<< "THX FOR PLAYING! UR CURRENT BALANCE IS RM "<< deposit<<"\n\n";
        cout<< setfill('+')<< setw(80)<<"\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the formula you are using to calculate the random number is wrong. Suppose that min is 10, and max is 12. Then the rand() % max could be, let's say, 10. Adding min (10), the number to guess would be 20 - far greater than max... It should be `secret = rand() % (max-min +1) + min;` (if your interval is [min, max]).

Now to your question - as far as I understood you want to know if the entered guess is a number. Here is what you can do:

```
    while(1)
   {
        cin >> guess;

         if(cin){
     if (guess > max){
         cout << "Too high!\n\n";
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore();
         continue;
     }
     else if (guess < min){
         cout << "Too low!\n\n";
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore();
         continue;
     }
     else if(guess != secret){
         deposit-=bet;
         cout<< "Sorry, U lose RM "<< bet;
     }
     else if(guess == secret){
         bet*=10;
         deposit+=bet;
         cout<< "\n\nCongratulation! U earn RM "<< bet;
     }
     break;
 }
 else
 {

     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore();
     cout << "Error! You did not enter a number!" << endl;
     continue;
 }
}
```

If the user didn't enter a number, the cin's fail flag will be up and you can use that.

Also, when trying again (`goto AA;`) you do not compute the random value again and you should. In order to get a different sequence of random numbers from rand() every time you start the program, you should seed the random generator from the current time. In the beginning of main, put `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));` What this does is that it gives the random generator a number and on its base it will generate random numbers. If the number is the same every time the program is started, the same numbers will be generated. But given the always changing current time, every time the sequence will be different.

Using *goto* can make your code very messy and can make bugs very hard to notice. Yes, it is a part of the language and it is there to be used, but one should be very careful with it. Especially if you are new to programming, try to refrain from using it. You could use `while(1)` or `for(;;)` if you need endless loops - you can get to the next iteration with `continue;` and stop them with `break;`.

Something is also wrong with the guessing loop. It seems that you cannot lose. You should decrease the deposit in the while loop and check if it is 0.

Edit: In the edited code you can see that whenever the user needs to enter the number again, you just skip the iteration with continue. This is also an example how you should deal with endless loops instead of using goto. With practice, you will get he hang of it. ;)

Edit 2:

```
    do{
     cout<< "Wanna play again (y/n)? "; 
     cin>> reply;

     if( reply!='y'&& reply!='n')      
         cout<< "\nReally? Ok, try again! \n";

 }while(reply!='n' && reply!='y');

 if( reply =='y')
         goto AA;

 if(reply=='n'){
     cout<< "\n\n\n"<< setw(80)<< setfill('+')<< "\n\n";
     cout<< setw(30)<< "THX FOR PLAYING! UR CURRENT BALANCE IS RM "<< deposit<< "\n\n";
     cout<< setfill('+')<< setw(80)<< "\n";
 }
```

This should make the reply cycle work. Your program should consist of different chunks of code for different purposes, and in this cycle you mixed up checking the correctness of the answer with what will happen if the answer is correct. It's easier first to do the first, and then to do the second thing. Using functions can generally help you with this.

Edit 3: In that new code you have a lot of problems with if statement. Firstly, what is !> ? I think you meant < or <= , !> does not exist, it won't even compile. Another thing - what happens when max or min is 0? You haven't covered that.

You use if-else chains a lot and in this case it is not necessarily needed. For example you don't need `if(min>0)` , you don't even need the else before it. If you don't enter one of the if statement - the input is correct and you can break, if you enter one of them - it has continue; in it and the code below is not executed. The same goes for the last if statement in the max if-else chain executed if the input is a number.

Anyway, you could do it a lot simpler. For example the min loop can be:

```
cout << "Pls enter the min of secret number\n";
while (!(cin >> min) || min<=0){

        cout << "Pls enter the min of secret number\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();

}
```

You could see that this will work if you realize that you should break if (cin && min>0). Now when you negate that in order to place it as the while condition it becomes (!cin || min<=0).

Anyway, I didn't see any other problem in the code, I tested it and it worked. And now without goto it looks a lot better.

Comment: what is the meaning of 'guess = -1' ?

Comment: Hi there! Well yes, the -1 is kind of pointless, I'm going to edit this. You still haven't moved the AA: label. It should be something like: int secret; `AA: secret = rand() % (max-min +1) + min;` Putting another cin in the else won't solve the problem because the user can enter another illegal symbol. I will show the solution of this in the edit.

Comment: Another thing - what do you use the again flag for? When goto is executed the program execution never returns to this point.
Apart from these issues the program seems to work correctly. Anyways, the code should be a lot cleaner and better structured.

Comment: hi, what is the meaning of 'while(1)' for?

Comment: Hi. The while(1) gives you an endless cycle which is broken only if the entered guess is correct (if not broken, the cycle will execute forever, since the condition is always true). If you just type cin>>guess; instead of continue; like you did before, there is no guarantee that this next input will be correct. Having an endless cycle, you could just continue to the next iteration until the input is correct. I will make another edit to make the play again part clear.

Comment: hi, I have updated my program again without using goto loop, and am now my program can't run because after the 'enter max value'. So any advice on the best route to do that would be nice I wish to get the similar output as the below output images link : [1]http://i62.tinypic.com/wjvuqb.png

Comment: Hi, I have updated my program, i can't get the user to cin again after type char by using do while loop. pls reply me asap..

Answer (score 4):

You are using goto, and if you are using goto, raptors will tear you to pieces. Do not, under any circumstances use goto!

But you can use functions to make your code a bit clearer. This wall of text and copy paste is really hard to read.